# Random number between x and y excluding a range of numbers inbetween

Tags: php, random

I am implementing a system at the moment where it needs to allocate a number in a certain range to a person, but not use any number that has been used before.
Keep in mind, both the number range and exclusion list are both going to be quite large.

Initially, I thought doing something like this would be best:

```
<?php 
  $start = 1;
  $end = 199999;
  $excluded = array(4,6,7,8,9,34);
  $found = FALSE;
  while (!$found) {
    $rand = mt_rand($start,$end);
    if (!in_array($rand,$excluded)) {
      $found = TRUE;
    }
  } 
?>
```

But I don't think this is ideal, there is the possibility of an infinite loop (or it taking a very long time / timing out the script).

I also thought about generating an array of all the numbers I needed, but surely a massive array would be worse? Also doing an array diff on 2 massive arrays would surely take a long time too?
Something like this:

```
<?php 
  $start = 1;
  $end = 199999;
  $allnums = range($start,$end);
  $excluded = array(4,6,7,8,9,34);
  $searcharray = array_diff($allnums,$excluded);
  $rand = array_rand($searcharray);
?>
```

So, my question would be which would be a better option? And is there another (better) way of doing this that someone has used before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Array's holding large amounts of data will use up a lot of memory, can you not use a database to hold these numbers in? That's generally what they are designed for.

Comment: Thats what I thought. The excluded numbers will be in a database after they get assigned. I guess the original range could be as well, how would I go about using that though? Store a row per number with a flag saying if it's excluded or not? Surely storing all the numbers would be a waste, considering they are consecutive already?

Comment: something like `SELECT ... WHERE number NOT IN (4,6,7,8,9,34) ORDER BY RAND()`?

Comment: You can still do the `mt_rand` part but just look the number generated up in a database instead of doing `in_array`. I would have a table with just 1 field which is the number - primary key/mediumint. It won't be that wasteful, if you have the field setup right proper databases are optimized for this kind of stuff.

Comment: So you're saying go with my first solution, just use sql instead of `in_array()`? Would a number of database calls be that much better than storing all the excluded in an array using one query? Sorry for all the questions, just trying to get this right before I dive in.

Comment: Yes go with the first solution but use sql, realistically how many numbers do you need to generate in 1 go?

Comment: It should only be 1 number each time. However the range will differ depending on what is being requested (each range group is going to be a maximum of 200000). This is going to be very active, so, for example, at one time there could be 150000 of the 200000 numbers unavailable, which is the main reason I thought it would be best to steer away from `mt_rand`.